# Cucumber аннотации

Tags: java, аннотации, cucumber

Как в Cucumber создать аннотации Before и After, чтобы они выполнялись перед и после каждого сценария?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@cucumber.api.java.Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario){
    SSystem.out.println("beforeScenario");
}

@cucumber.api.java.After
public static void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
    System.out.println("after Scenario");
}
```